# Is this a bug? I am following Lightning Components Developer Guide and

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am copy pasting the code for creating the Expense tracker app.

This is what I get...
Is this kind of a bug? UI doesn't look good at all...

Could anyone please assist? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: 1) Did you use all css as in example?
2) Do you have custom css? 
3) Which browser is being used?
4)Did you try refresh page with cache clear?
5) Can you please post your code?
I think when you reread all those questions, you can find answer by yourself=)

Comment: 1. Yes
2. No
3. Chrome
4. Yes.
5. Took the code directly from step1 and step2. Checked with Chrome debugger and all files are loaded.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app_step2_cmp.htm

Comment: You are right, thats example styling issue - use in css     left: 98%;
    top: 56%; and      left: 48%;
    top: 56%; respectively, and it would be displayed as in example. btw, checkbox is fine in my case

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  how can I report this to Salesforce?

Comment: @RonDaniel There should be a "Feedback" pop-out tab that looks like [+] on the right-hand side of your browser on the page where the error is. Salesforce reads and sometimes responds to feedback through that interface. I use it on Trailhead. Ad-blocking software or other browser addons might interfere with it, so try a different/extensionless browser if you don't see it or the link doesn't work.